# Apache + php-fpm : headers stripped?

Tags: apache, header, php

I had a PHP framework setup to use the php5_module for apache. The framework is custom written for a specific purpose and handles lots of things, for example the headers. On the new dev server there is a php-fpm instance setup and the old:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ core.php
```

is replaced by `ProxyPassMatch`:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^(.*)$ unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock|fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/path/to/core.php
```

everything works great so far but it seems the headers that the php script adds are stripped or cause some kind of errors in the apache log.

Is it possible to use just the headers that the script adds and apache does not touch the headers at all?

Answer (score 0):

That's just because you a saying that it's proxy server, which means for security reasons that's purged. as far as I can remember it's not really possible easily.

Anyway my suggestion is to use Nginx with PHP-FPM and if you need to use the Apache use the php module for apache as it's designed this way.

Hope it helped answering your question.

Comment: There was a typo in some of the headers and there an option set to strip invalid headers